# Timer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that timer doesn't pause correctly. When I hit pause it looks like it has stopped but actually it continues to cycle, and when I hit start it doesn't continue from where I paused, but from the location it had reached.

```
<div class="stopwatch">
    <span>00:00:00,000</span><br />
    <div class="btn start">play</div>
    <div class="btn pause">pause</div>
    <div class="btn reset">reset</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function (){  
    var reload = 1000/60;  
    var timer = null;  
    var startTime = 0;  
    var btn = $('.stopwatch a');  
    var count = $('.stopwatch span');  
    var pause = false;

    $('.pause').click(function (){
        pause = true; 
    });
    $('.start').click(function (){
        pause = false; 
    });
    $('.reset').click(function (){
        return ( (count.text('00:00:00,000')) && (timer = 0) );
    });

    function zero(num, length) {  
        if ( typeof(length) == 'undefined' ) length = 2;  

        while ( num.toString().length < length ) {  
            num = '0' + num;  
        }  
        return num;  
    }  

    function zero_format(time){  
        return zero(time.getUTCHours()) + ':' + zero(time.getMinutes()) + ':' + zero(time.getSeconds()) + ',' + zero(time.getMilliseconds()); 
    }  

    $('.start').click( function (){  
        if ( !timer ){  
            startTime = new Date();  
            timer = setInterval( function (){  
                if ( pause ){
                    return;
                }

                var currentTime = new Date(new Date() - startTime);  
                count.text(zero_format(currentTime));  
            }, reload);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Code works fine to me. Can you make your question more clear please?

Comment: I see it works wrong after pause -> start. It looks like timer is not actually stopped

Comment: I thought that's why it's "pause" and not stop. Like for taking lap times but it continues counting.

Comment: @FAngel: That's because of this `var currentTime = new Date(new Date() - startTime);`. When it's paused, this calculation isn't adjusted for the paused time. It's not clear whether this is deliberate or not.

Comment: @MattBurland I know. My comment was just to confirm that there is a problem. Because Ergec told that everything works fine

Comment: @NikiLichev Check my updated answer (Update 1) and see if this is what you need.

Comment: @Ergec OP is looking for a timer rather than a stop watch with lap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two handlers for `$('.start')`.

Try this: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ryXMy/)

```
$('.start').click(function (){  
    if ( !timer ){  
        startTime = new Date();  
        timer = setInterval( function (){  
            if ( pause ){
                return;
            }

            var currentTime = new Date(new Date() - startTime);  
            count.text(zero_format(currentTime));  
        }, reload);
    } else {
        pause = false; 
    }

    return false;
});
```

And **remove** this:

```
$('.start').click(function (){
    pause = false; 
});
```

**Update 1**

If you need a stopwatch, not a lap timer, then here is the code: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H3ds3/)

```
var savedTime;
var additional = 0;

$('.pause').click(function (){
    savedTime = new Date(); 
    pause = true; 
});

$('.reset').click(function (){
    count.text('00:00:00,000');
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    additional = 0;
});

$('.start').click( function (){  
    if ( !timer ){  
              startTime = new Date();  
        timer = setInterval( function (){  
            if ( pause ){
                return;
            }

            currentTime = new Date(new Date() - startTime - additional);  
            count.text(zero_format(currentTime));  
        }, reload);

        pause = false;
    }

    if(pause == true) {
        additional += new Date() - savedTime;
        pause = false; 
    }

   return false;
});
```

Comment: Updated answer and demo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust startTime variable because you are still calculating time diff with datetime which was created when start was pushed for the first time

Answer (score 0):

I would promote `currentTime` to the outer scope and keep track of the time of the last tick in the outer scope as well. Then with each tick, update `currentTime` by adding the difference between the last tick and the current tick, instead of time since the start. That way it will be properly paused.

Also you will need to add to the `currentTime` when first pause and reset the last tick when you restart.